# Swing Chat HTML formatted messages

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jscrollpane, jlabel

I'm trying to make a chat client to Swing. I need that message in the history of correspondence were formatted in HTML.

The problem I tried to solve with JTextPane, as it supports HTML formatting. When I did, just text display, in principle everything was normal.

But when I added emoticons using the HTML tag `<img>`, each time a new message, all text in the window of correspondence started twitching.

How I did it:

```
jTextPane.setText ("message");
```

When it was, the new message, I did so

```
jTextPane.setText ("message" + "new message"); etc.
```

The result had been the principle of "snake" of Tetris. As a result, I did not like how it works.

So please tell me whether it is possible to deduce that new messages using JLabel adding them to JScrollpane? How to make every new post was a separate element?

```
    String[] split = text.split("\t\t");

    String time = split[0].split("\t")[2].split(", ")[1];
    String sender = split[0].split("\t")[3];
    String message = split[1];

    if (!jTextPane.getText().equals("Please log in!")) {
        oldMsg = jTextPane.getText().substring(jTextPane.getText().indexOf("<body>") + 6, jTextPane.getText().lastIndexOf("</body>"));

        if(sender.equalsIgnoreCase(login.getText())) {
            msg = "<div style=\"text-align:right\">" + checkMsgOnSmile(message) + " " + "<b>" + " :" + checkSenderOnColor(sender) + "</b>" + "<span style=\"font-size:10pt\">[" + time + "]</span></div>";
        } else {
            msg = "<div style=\"\"><span style=\"font-size:10pt\">[" + time + "]</span> " + "<b>" + checkSenderOnColor(sender) + ":" + "</b>" + " " + checkMsgOnSmile(message);
        }

        String[] check = (oldMsg + msg).split("<br>");
        if (check.length > 99) {
            ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(check));
            arrayList.remove(0);
            String str = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
                str = str + arrayList.get(i).toString() + "<br>";
            }

            jTextPane.setText(str);
        } else {
            oldMsg = oldMsg.replaceAll("<span><font size=\"10pt\">", "<span style=\"font-size:10pt\">");
            oldMsg = oldMsg.replaceAll("</font></span>", "</span>");
            jTextPane.setText(oldMsg + msg + "<br>");
        }
    }
```

Can it be replaced by a JLabel and JScrollPane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to display text with different colors, fonts etc.., then I find working with text and attributes is easier than using HTML. A simple example would be code like:

```
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
textPane.setText( "Hello:" );
textPane.setEditable(false);
StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();

//  Define a keyword attribute

Simple AttributeSet keyWord = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setForeground(keyWord, Color.RED);
StyleConstants.setBackground(keyWord, Color.YELLOW);
StyleConstants.setBold(keyWord, true);

//  Add some text

try
{
    doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "\nAnother line of text", keyWord );
}
catch(Exception e) {}
```

Comment: I want get rid of the JTextPane.  And make the display of new messages using JLabel. Can I make it so that when a new message arrives, create a new instance of JLabel it puts a new message, then this JLabel added to the JScrollPane.

Comment: @Elsrix, Why would you use a JLabel? A JLabel is designed for simple text. A JTextPane is designed for styled text.

Comment: sorry, i not fully checked everything!
I thought that the JLabel, is also able to handle HTML tags, as well as JTextPane.

Tell me, how do I optimize your code so that when a new message arrives, it gradually appeared in the history of correspondence?

And now it is very choppy when a new message arrives.

Comment: @Elsrix, `I thought that the JLabel, is also able to handle HTML tags` - it is. If you want to do this, then create a JPanel using a vertical BoxLayout. Then you create the label and add it to the panel. You then need to invoke revalidate() and repaint(). `so that when a new message arrives, it gradually appeared in the history of correspondence?` - I don't understand the comment. The text will be added to the text pane every time you invoke the insertString(...) method, so it is done gradually every time your client code receives the text.